# Unexplained Langauge Changing

Tags: language-support

I'm occasionally have my keyboard switch mode switch from British English to American English while I am typing (or more generally have the system loadedd up doing normal things) and I'm unable to identify the cause.

This can be fixed by clicking on the scrabble tile language (top right) and reclicking on EN (it still says English before you click) - but I'm curious as to what is going on. Has anyone encountered (and solved) this before?

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Ubuntu (16.04) I can left click and select parameters (not sure if I correctly translated the menu item) - there I can see all layouts and combination for layout switch. One can also add/remove layouts from that dialog.
Is this what you asking?